# Keycloak extension with dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, wildfly, keycloak

I'm creating a Keycloak extension with dependencies. I added the entry on the `pom.xml` like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20160810</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I deployed it to Keycloak:

```
mvn clean install wildfly:deploy
```

But when I run it, I got the error:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject from [Module "deployment.keycloak-authenticator.jar" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 66 more
```

How to add dependencies to extensions in Keycloak?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a better way, deploy as a EAR archive. This project shows how to: https://github.com/stianst/keycloak-experimental/tree/master/fido-u2f

Answer (score 12):

You have to [create your SPI dependencies as jboss modules](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#using-the-keycloak-deployer).

Steps:

1. Add a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file in src/main/resources/META-INF directory or your SPI with something like this ([oficial documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly)):

   ```
   <jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
       <dependencies>
           <module name="org.json.json" />
       </dependencies>
   </deployment>
   </jboss-deployment-structure>
   ```
2. Make $KEYCLOAK_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/json/json/main directory
3. Add json-20160810.jar in created dir
4. Add a module.xml file in same dir with this content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="org.json.json">
       <properties>
           <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
       </properties>

       <resources>
           <resource-root path="json-20160810.jar"/>
       </resources>

       <dependencies>
       </dependencies>
   </module>
   ```
5. Compile your SPI
6. Restart keycloak
7. Redeploy your SPI

Comment: There a better way, deploy as a EAR archive. This project shows how to: https://github.com/stianst/keycloak-experimental/tree/master/fido-u2f